# Test Webservice Method in Visual Studio: why does it say runs successfully without running the test and test fails?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created the default webservice asmx hello world :

```
namespace WebServiceHello
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

I then generate a MS Test with Visual Studio and set expected value:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\temp\\WebServiceHello\\WebServiceHello", "/")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost:7352/")]
    public void HelloWorldTest()
    {
        Service1 target = new Service1(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string expected = "Hello World"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string actual;
        actual = target.HelloWorld();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        // Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

but I got this error message:

> The Web request
>   'http://localhost:7352/' completed
>   successfully without running the test.
>   This can occur when configuring the
>   Web application for testing fails (an
>   ASP.NET server error occurs when
>   processing the request), or when no
>   ASP.NET page is executed (the URL may
>   point to an HTML page, a Web service,
>   or a directory listing). Running tests
>   in ASP.NET requires the URL to resolve
>   to an ASP.NET page and for the page to
>   execute properly up to the Load event.
>   The response from the request is
>   stored in the file
>   'WebRequestResponse_HelloWorldTest.html'
>   with the test results; typically this
>   file can be opened with a Web browser
>   to view its contents.

and as Test Files :
WebRequestResponse_HelloWorldTest.html
which contains

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Directory Listing -- /</title>
        <style>
            body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: 8pt;color:black;} 
            p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
            b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
            h1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
            h2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
            pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: 8pt}
            .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
            .version {color: gray;}
            .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
            .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">

    <h2> <i>Directory Listing -- /</i> </h2></span>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

<PRE>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM        &lt;dir&gt; <A href="App_Data/">App_Data</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:40 PM        &lt;dir&gt; <A href="bin/">bin</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM        &lt;dir&gt; <A href="obj/">obj</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM        &lt;dir&gt; <A href="Properties/">Properties</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM           97 <A href="Service1.asmx">Service1.asmx</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM          572 <A href="Service1.asmx.cs">Service1.asmx.cs</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:44 PM        3,551 <A href="Web.config">Web.config</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM          968 <A href="web.config.backup">web.config.backup</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM        1,285 <A href="Web.Debug.config">Web.Debug.config</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:39 PM        1,346 <A href="Web.Release.config">Web.Release.config</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:40 PM        3,805 <A href="WebServiceHello.csproj">WebServiceHello.csproj</A>
 Saturday, September 25, 2010 06:40 PM        1,086 <A href="WebServiceHello.csproj.user">WebServiceHello.csproj.user</A>
</PRE>
            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

              <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
```

The test shouldn't fail since actual is expected so what I did setup wrongly ?

Answer (score 4):

Create Default.aspx page in project with service

Answer (score 0):

Answer valid for: Vista, VS2008 (may work for VS2010)

- Run VS as admin (it's enough to be part of Administrators group)
- Create Default.aspx page in the project

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243399(v=vs.90).aspx